# SQLiteLog﹕no such column

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am trying to execute a basic login form in android. This is the trimmed version of the code. Basically, if the user enters an invalid login details it should trigger an alert. However, I'm getting an error when ever I click on the Login Button.
Below posted is my code.

```
Alert_Dialouge alert = new Alert_Dialouge();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
    context = this;
    final DataBaseHelper hl =  new DataBaseHelper(context);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Main_activity.this).create();
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            c = c + 1;
            EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            EditText pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pwd.getText().toString();

            db = hl.getReadableDatabase();
            db.beginTransaction();
            String select = "SELECT * from  " + " " + hl.TABLE_NAME+ " "+ 
            "where Username = admin and Password = admin;" ;
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, null);
            if ((username.equals("") && password.equals("")) ||  
            password.equals("") || username.equals("")||c.getCount()==0) {

                alert.showAlertDialog(Main_activity.this, "Please enter your credentials", false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            } else if(c.getCount()>0) {


                      c.moveToFirst();
                System.out.println("hiiii");

            }
            c.close();
        }
       });
        }
       }
```

Below posted is my Database Helper class

```
      public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="db1";
     public static  final int DATABASE_VERSION=8;
     public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
     public static final String TABLE_NAME ="malware_users1";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +"  
"+ TABLE_NAME +"( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Username 
 VARCHAR(255),Password VARCHAR(255))";


     public static final String DELETE_TABLE= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +  
     TABLE_NAME;


    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
     @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
      }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLE);
    oncreate(db);
      }


  public void insertData(String Username,String Password)
    {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    ContentValues values;

    try
    {
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Username",Username);
        values.put("Password",Password);
        long i =db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        Log.i("Insert",i+"");
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
     }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
                    }
                   }
                  }
```

Below posted is the stackTrace:

```
  no such column: admin (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * from   
  malware_users1 where Username = admin and Password = admin;
        at  
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
  Method) at 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
```

Comment: SELECT * from  " + " " + hl.TABLE_NAME+ " "+ 
            "where Username = 'admin' and Password = 'admin';

You missed the '' around the where-clause values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

much better would be to use the selectionArgs argument

```
 String select = "SELECT * from  " + " " + hl.TABLE_NAME+ " "+ 
                                      "where Username = ? and Password = ? "; 
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery(select, new String[] {"admin", "admin});
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) you can find the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Please check the query which I had changed

```
String select = "SELECT * from  " + " " + hl.TABLE_NAME+ " "+ 
            "where Username = 'admin' and Password = 'admin'" ;
```

Please check it and let me know its solved the issue or not ?

Answer (score 1):

in your b1 clicklistener the problem is with your select query

change this

```
   String select = "SELECT * from  " + " " + hl.TABLE_NAME+ " "+ 
        "where Username = admin and Password = admin;" ;
```

to

```
  String username="admin";
  String password="admin";
   String select = "SELECT * from " + hl.TABLE_NAME+
            " where Username ='"+username+"' and Password ='"+password+"'" ;
```